# Trying to toggle a view on/off using tags

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to toggle a view on and off which works, but what i need to know is if I am abusing tags with this method. If so is there a better way?

```
    - (IBAction) myButton:(UIButton*)sender {

    if ([myLabelText.text isEqualToString:@""]) 
{
        // do nothing

    } else {

            if ( sender.tag )
        {
            sender.tag = 0;
            [[self firstView] setHidden:YES];

        } else {

            sender.tag = 1;
            firstView.alpha = 100;
            [[self firstView] setHidden:NO];

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `tag` property for anything you like, but in this case you can toggle the visibility without using it:

```
[self firstView].hidden = ![self firstView].hidden;
```

Also, the valid range for `UIView`'s `alpha` property is from 0.0 to 1.0. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. I was thinking that i needed to use float values for the alpha setting, but was in a hurry to post. Thanks for that too.